# generate table (like calendar) for one month with php

Tags: php

I have some question about php.
I would like to generate a table displaying results of my mysql database for one month classified by week.

On my database I have a table named "RESULT" with idresult, result, date (Y-m-d format).

Here an php/html example that I would like for november 2014 :

```
<?php
echo '
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
   <td>November 2014</td>
   <td>01 to 02</td>
   <td>03 to 09</td>
   <td>10 to 16</td>
   <td>17 to 23</td>
   <td>24 to 30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td >Monday</td>
   <td ></td>
   <td >2014.11.03 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.10 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.17 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.24 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
   <td >Tuesday</td>
   <td ></td>
   <td >2014.11.04 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.11 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.18 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.25 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
   <td >Wednesday</td>
   <td ></td>
   <td >2014.11.05 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.12 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.19 : '.$result[date].'</td>
   <td >2014.11.26 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
    <td >Thursday</td>
    <td ></td>
    <td >2014.11.06 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.13 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.20 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.27 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
    <td >Friday</td>
    <td ></td>
    <td >2014.11.07 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.14 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.21 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.28 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
    <td >Saturday</td>
    <td >2014.11.01 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.08 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.15 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.22 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.29 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
    <td >Sunday</td>
    <td >2014.11.02 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.09 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.16 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.23 : '.$result[date].'</td>
    <td >2014.11.30 : '.$result[date].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
?>
```

I tried to do php script using dates and loop for() but my script is very big (500lines) and..very ugly :)
Do you you have an idea to help me ?  thank you !

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand what do You want exactly?

Comment: <tr>
   <td >Monday</td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
</tr> empty rows? Only Monday?

Comment: Sorry My post was unclear. I changed it to explain my problem better.

Comment: OK, i understand now. Have answer but waiting for open this questions. Be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
<?php

$resultA['2014-11-02']=17;
$resultA['2014-11-12']=5;
$resultA['2014-11-13']=3;
$resultA['2014-11-14']=15;
$resultA['2014-11-15']=16;


function draw_calendar($month,$year,$resultA)
{

  /* draw table */
  $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

  /* table headings */
  $headings = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
  $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

  /* days and weeks vars now ... */
  $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $days_in_this_week = 1;
  $day_counter = 0;



  /* row for week one */
  $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

  /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
  for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
  endfor;

  /* keep going with days.... */
  for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
      /* add in the day number */
      $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        $date=date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year));

        $tdHTML='';        
        if(isset($resultA[$date])) $tdHTML=$resultA[$date];

      $calendar.=$tdHTML;      

    $calendar.= '</td>';

    if($running_day == 6):
      $calendar.= '</tr>';
      if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
        $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
      endif;
      $running_day = -1;
      $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
  endfor;

  /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
  if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
      $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
    endfor;
  endif;

  /* final row */
  $calendar.= '</tr>';

  /* end the table */
  $calendar.= '</table>';

  /* all done, return result */
  return $calendar;
}


?>

<style>
table.calendar    { border-left:1px solid #6897c3; }
td{vertical-align: top;}
tr.calendar-row  {  }
td.calendar-day  { min-height:80px; font-size:11px; position:relative; } * html div.calendar-day { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day:hover  { background:#eceff5; }
td.calendar-day-np  { background:#eee; min-height:80px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day-head { background:#6897c3; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #6897c3; border-top:1px solid #6897c3; border-right:1px solid #6897c3; color: #fff; }
div.day-number    { background:#6897c3; padding:5px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; float:right; margin:-5px -5px 0 0; width:20px; text-align:center; }
/* shared */
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #6897c3; border-right:1px solid #6897c3; }

</style>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo draw_calendar(11,2014,$resultA);  ?>
</body>
</html>
```